# Scrapy not defined

Tags: scrapy, undefined

I'm trying to write a web crawler using VSC & encountered the error. Below are my codes.

```
class spider1(scrapy.Spider):
name = 'Wikipedia'
start_urls = <kbd>['https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battery_(electricity)']</kbd>
def parse(self, response):pass
```

May I know what's wrong?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

try to import scrapy first

```
import scrapy
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work, you are missing a scrapy import that is being used to import a parent of Spider1

```
import scrapy

class spider1(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'Wikipedia'
    start_urls = ['https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battery_(electricity)']
    def parse(self, response):
        pass
```